# Migrate Silverlight check for ElevatedPermission to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I am working for a customer which has a legacy Silverlight application that is being migrated for ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework still). This app has some reports that can only be viewed according to the following condition:

```
public static bool HasElevatedPrivilegies
{
     get
     {
         return !Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser && Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions;
     }
}
```

So, if this returns `true`, user can view the report. Basically, that means that employees can only view reports if they are using the company's laptop. If they try to do it from a private laptop or a public one, the property above returns `false` and an error message is shown.

Now, the team has to implement this functionality in MVC. Actually, we have an api on MVC and frontend in Angular.

Is there a way to accomplish the same result using Angular/MVC? Has anyone ever faced something like this before?

Sorry if this question looks like more a brainstorm session than actually a question.

Many thanks!

Comment: `employees can only view reports if they are using the company's laptop.` that's not what this code does. It checks that the SPA is running inside a browser and its out-of-browser configuration was set to require elevated privileges. That doesn't mean users are using the company laptop, it means the app was deployed using an obscure manifest. One that can be replicated by others.

Comment: The *real* problem, how to authenticate SPAs, is a major issue, discussed in the docs of all SPA frameworks. You can't get real security in the browser as a user can always inspect and modify things. You can hide UI parts based on settings retrieved from the server though. You can use eg OpenID and JWT to secure all server calls. In more modular architectures you and send only the permitted modules/UI elements to the browser, eg based on dynamic loading and navigation routes. The server will have to validate the JWT and ensure the user is allowed to use this or that UI or make that call

Comment: OpenID can use multiple claims when contacting an OpenID server to authenticate. That server could require that all connections are made used a certificate issued by the company's trust root. I'm not sure how these flows work but they're certainly possible

Comment: But according to the employees, it was done like this to block viewing reports from private/public laptops... so only using the company's laptop they can view the report. But, I agree with you, sure. 

We already have JWT working for the calls etc... but we don't know how to "export" this feature to Angular/MVC... we could restrict the URLs in Angular via guards, but how to check if a user is using company's laptop or not?

Comment: I just read what you said about OpenID, but it is a way to go

Comment: But your said "all connections are made user a certified issued by the company"... but the site is already using HTTPS, so in theory if I log into the site, no mattering if I am in a private/public laptop or company's laptop, the caonnections to the server will always be behind the certificate, right? Because I am accessing the site which is already using the certificate

Comment: The [ASP.NET Core Identity docs: Authentication and Authorization in SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) cover this but things got interesting when the open-source ASP.NET Core Identity Server became dual-licensed. You can still use it, and the tutorials, to get started and investigate the various flows.